# Functional JS - forEach function not working

Tags: javascript, foreach, count, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to practice functional programming and I started by working with forEach and reduce to count zeroes in a given array (a problem in eloquent JavaScript chapter 5). But I do not understand why my code works in some instances but not others.

The code below doesn't work and leaving out the else statement seems to be the problem. But why is the else statement necessary here and not in some of the cases I post towards the end of the post?

```js
function forEach(arr, action) {
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   action(arr[i]);
  }
}

function reduce(cb, start, array) {
  forEach(array, function(el) { start = cb(start, el); });
 return start;
}

function countZeroes(array) {
  function counter(total, element) {
    if(element === 0) return total + 1; //excluding else statement seems to be the issue but why?
  }
  return reduce(counter, 0, array);
}
console.log(countZeroes([0,1,0,2,0,3, 0,4,2,0])); //returns NaN
```

If I rewrite the function as such with an else statement it works:

```js
function forEach(arr, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    action(arr[i]);
  }
}

function reduce(cb, start, array) {
  forEach(array, function(el) {
    start = cb(start, el);
  });
  return start;
}

function countZeroes(arr) {
  function counter(total, element) {
    if (element === 0) {
      return total + 1;
    } else {
      return total;
    }
  }
  return reduce(counter, 0, arr);
}

console.log(countZeroes([0, 1, 2, 0]));
```

However, the code does not require the else statement in the cases below, why?

```js
function countTarget(arr, target) {
 var counter = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === target) counter++;  //no else statement required here
  }
  return counter;
}
console.log(countTarget([0,1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0], 0));
```

```js
function forEach(arr, action) {
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   action(arr[i]);
  }
}

function test(a) {
  return a === 0;
}

function countTarget(arr, target) {
  var counter = 0;
  forEach(arr, function(el) {
    if (test(el)) counter++;
  });
  return counter;
}
console.log(countTarget([1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0], 0));
```

I would appreciate thoughts.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue.

Comment: If you only look at the 1st snippet of code, the countZeroes returns a NaN. Why is it doing that?

Comment: Take a look at the native reduce function for arrays to simplify your code and help with reasoning https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever gets returned from your `counter` function is the passed to the next call to `counter`. Therefore, you need to return *something* on your counter function. If the condition doesn't get satisfied, return the unaffected total:

```
function counter(total, element) {
   return (element === 0) ? total + 1 : total;
}
```

**Explanation:** your `counter` function increments a "total" value depending on some logic and returns the incremented value. The returned value is then passed to the `counter` function again. Your counter function has a code path which doesn't return a value (when the if statement doesn't pass). In this case, you're not returning anything... which is similar to returning `undefined`. If you were to isolate this, it would look kind of like this:

```
// Let's say your current "total" count is 15
var total = counter(15, 2);
console.log(total); //-> undefined
```

Since `2 !== 0` - the condition didn't pass and the result of the function is `undefined`. Now, the next time counter is called, it will look like this:

```
var total = counter(undefined, 0);
```

Since `0 === 0`, the condition will pass, and it will try to increment the total... which is `undefined`:

```
return undefined + 1; //-> NaN
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I was thinking along the same lines.  The book did solve the problem with the ternary operator but I wanted to figure out why the if  didn't work. I fixed it by putting a return statement after the if:     if(element ==0) { total = total + 1; } return total;     --- I still need to understand what was happening when nothing was returned. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation. Let me know if that clears it up for you.

Comment: The added explanation was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It is courteous to accept an answer if it helped you solve your problem ;). If you need more assistance, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't know there was such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter(total, element) {
    if(element === 0) return total + 1; //excluding else statement seems to be the issue but why?
}
```

in this function, you are returning some value (`total + 1`) when the `element` is 0. so for every other case this function returns undefined as you did not specify any value for `else` case.

`undefined` + `number` = `NaN`

you can check the returned value from `counter` like this

```
forEach(array, function(el) {
    console.log(start);
    start = cb(start, el); 
});
```

#### case 1: no else

```
console.log(countZeroes([0,1,0,2,0,3, 0,4,2,0]));
```

logged values
    `0` `1` `undefined` `NaN` so on

#### case 2: with else

```
console.log(countZeroes([0,1,0,2,0,3, 0,4,2,0]));
```

logged values 
    `0` `1` `1` `2` `2` `3` so on

#### EDIT

when you define a function like below

```
function f_name() {
    // calculations
    return some_value;
}
```

javascript implements it as

```
function f_name() {
    // calculations
    return some_value;
    return undefined; // implied by javascript
}
```

a `function` can have multiple `return` statements and function returns when it encounters a `return` in the execution flow and the remaining code becomes unreachable.

so, in your case

```
function counter(total, element) {
    if(element === 0) return total + 1; //excluding else statement seems to be the issue but why?
    return undefined; // implied
}
```

when the `element` value is `0`, the function return `total + 1` and the remaining code(`return undefined;`) becomes unrechable but when `element` is not `0`, the function executes `return undefined`.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: If we follow that logic then why does this not require an else statement?     function test(a) {  return a === 0; }

    function countTarget(arr, target) {
      var counter = 0;
      forEach(arr, function(el) {
        if (test(el)) counter++;
      });
      return counter; </code>

Comment: `function test(a) { return a === 0; }` this code always returns a value. either `true` or `false`. But `function test(a) { if(condition) return a === 0; }`, here the function retunrs `true` or `flase` only when `condition` is truthy. when it is falsy the function returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks this also clarifies.